# QGIS Plugin reload is incomplete

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pycharm

I am developing a QGIS Plugin in PyCharm. I use the QGIS Plugin `"Plugin reloader"` to reload the plugin when I want to test the plugin. But changes in the code are not applied on running the plugin most of the time.

I have to reload the plugin a second time or oftener to update the plugin (I am waiting till the `reload-info-dialog` disappears, before testing the plugin). The likelihood to reload the code, in the plugin-base-path is higher than in a containing directory.

After restarting qgis, the plugin works as expected. But I cannot restart QGIS for every test!

Edit:
I use QGIS 3.8 on Windows 10 (Plugin reloader 0.7.8)

The "plugin-base-path" is the plugin-directory where my_plugin.py is. Here i have subdirectories to handle the plugin-files.

Comment: Please add some information. QGIS-Version? Operating system? And i don't understand what you mean by plugin-base-path and containing directory. Do you have to copy the plugin each time or do you use *make*? Do you save all files in PyCharm before reloading?

Comment: I have edited the question and added some infos. Yes, I save the files before reloading. I don't know what you mean with "Do you have to copy the plugin each time or do you use make". I change the code in pycharm, save the file, reload the plugin in qgis and then I want to use the plugin.

Comment: Do you close your plugin dialog or dockwidget before reloading? Maybe some modules remain in memory...

Comment: No, i wait till the plugin dialog closes by itselfe.

Comment: After some tests, the 'Plugin Reloader'-plugin works only reliable for me, when all the necessary files for the plugin are in the 'plugin-base'-directory (the directory where my_plugin.py is). When the files are in sub-directories to this, the 'Plugin Reloader'-plugin do not update these files.

Comment: It could be a wrong import. Because a plugin is a python package there has to be an `__init__.py` in every subdirectory. Also imports inside a package have to be relative with python3. If this is not the case, plugin reloader fails: see https://github.com/borysiasty/plugin_reloader/issues/14

Comment: I have an ____init____.py in every subdirectory and make imports relative from the maindirectory (where my_plugin.py ist)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I has the same one in QGIS 3.28.

Comment: @eug100: I use only the 'plugin-base'-directory and no sub-directories and all works fine.